# Qt QPushbutton Icon underneath Text

Tags: qt, pyqt

When I create a QPushButton with an Icon it by default displays the text to the right of the icon. Is there a way to have the text display above the icon?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a `QToolButton` instead. This class has a method named `setToolButtonStyle`, which allows you to do exactly what you want.

In C++ (I have never messed with PyQt):

```
QToolButton *button = new QToolButton(this);
button->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
```

Link to the C++ docs: [QToolButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbutton.html#toolButtonStyle-prop) and [Qt::ToolButtonStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ToolButtonStyle-enum)

Comment: That's the opposite of what OP asks :).